# How can I compile a C program that I've edited in Vi or Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to compile and run a c project from vim and vi

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 printf("Hello! This is a test prgoram.\n");
 return 0;
}
```

and I get this output

```
madona@madona-Java ~ $ vi demo.c

[No write since last change]
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Press ENTER or type command to continue
[No write since last change]
gcc: error: demo.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

shell returned 4
```

after using this `:!gcc demo.c`. What am I doing wrong?

I also had this issue when I tried to run:

```
gcc -o demo demo.c
gcc: error: demo.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text; paste the *actual text*...

Comment: Okay, i didnt know.

Comment: The same way you compile usually. You can see from this that your demo.c isn't in the folder you think it is! Type `ls` to confirm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just because you ran

```
vi demo.c
```

does not mean a file `demo.c` was created. It isn't created until you write the buffer to disk for the first time.

Simply write the buffer to disk before compiling:

```
:w
```

This is confirmed by the message `[No write since last change]` you see. This message means the buffer changed (in that you created the buffer called `demo.c`) but was not written to disk after modifications.

Comment: try `:make` after saving with `:w`

Comment: @balki I think the OP already has his/her own compilation flow set up; the problem was that the file had not been saved to disk yet. Unfortunately, the current title of the question is somewhat misleading.